# Span of a Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space and $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,w \in V$

If $w \in \text{span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$, then $w \in \text{span}\{v_1,v_2\}$ - I believe this to be false, however I cannot come up with an appropriate counter-example, what would be a suitable counter-example?

If $w \in \text{span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$, then $w \in \text{span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ - I believe this to be true but what is an appropriate proof to show this is true?

Answer (score 1):

1.- $w\in {\rm span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3\} \Rightarrow w\in {\rm span}\{v_1,v_2\}$ is FALSE.

Take, for example, $v_1=(1,0,0)$, $v_2=(0,1,0)$ and $w=v_3=(0,0,1)$. Or just take any two vectors $v_1,v_2$ and $w=v_3$ independent to them.

2.- $w\in {\rm span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3\} \Rightarrow w\in {\rm span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ is TRUE.

If $w\in {\rm span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3\} $,then $w=\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\alpha_3v_3 =
\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\alpha_3v_3 +0\cdot v_4$, so $w\in{\rm span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, we have that

$$ w ∈ \operatorname{span}{v_1,v_2,v_3} \implies w ∈ \operatorname{span}{v_1,v_2}$$

only if $v_3=av_1+bv_2$.

Answer (score 0):

1. What about $v_3$? (Given ofcourse that $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearly independent)
2. If $w\in\text{span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$, then $$w=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3\tag{1}$$ You can also write $(1)$ as $$w=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3\tag{2}+0v_4$$ so $w\in\text{span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$